# How do I install a evaluation edition of SQL 2016 SP1 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, trial

Is there a way to install an evaluation edition of SQL 2016 SP1 Standard Edition?  I need to run some performance testing on a Standard Edition install as part of the purchase justification process.

Comment: Contact Microsoft and ask them if there is an evaluation version available. We're not them (there is no *microsoft.com* in the URL here).

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126538/how-to-install-microsoft-sql-server-2014-standard-edition-on-trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to run SQL Standard without a license is through MSDN.  Alternatively you can use pay-as-you-go Azure VMs SQL built in.

Comment: David, so through MSDN I would be able to download a trial of 2016 SP1 Standard Edition?  I am really trying to build a realistic test environment so that I can justify to management upgrading from 2008R2.  We are currently running Standard Edition, and I am wary of testing with all the capabilities of Enterprise Edition and then not being able to actually use it after purchasing.

Comment: Yes.  MSDN Pro, Enterprise, and Platforms subscribers have access to download and rights to run in dev/test a vast library of current and past Microsoft software.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your help.  I really appreciate it.  I assume there is a cost to Pro, Enterprise, and Platform subscription.  What are the costs for each?